# How to change datatype nvarchar to bigint in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I am using SQL Server Management Studio and have a table defined with `S_id AS NVARCHAR (80)`, and this cannot be changed. Now there are some values coming as AEC123, ID-33009, 456KP889 which according to me are causing an error in my following query

```
CONVERT(bigint, S_id)
```

and I get an error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

How do I fix this? If there are values of `S_id` such as described above should be excluded from my `SELECT` statement, how do I achieve this?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You can test if the value is BIGINT using a strategy like what's discussed in the question link posted above.

Comment: Use `TRY_CONVERT` instead. Though why are you converting the value to a `bigint` in the first place when the values clearly *aren't* a numerical value. This smells like an [XY problem](xyproblem.info) to me.

Comment: @ThomA there are some numerical values too such as 2193,44567689, etc..

Comment: How do I use TRY_CONVERT ? I am not able to get the syntax @ThomA

Comment: The syntax is identical to `CONVERT`'s, @Sca . `TRY_CONVERT(<Data Type>, <Expression> {, <Style Code>} )`

Comment: Got it but still throws an error : Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT` *cannot* throw that error. This means you're trying to change the datatype to an `bigint` somewhere else.

Comment: @ThomA it did work, thank you! although I read that if this function cannot convert, it will return a NULL and currently this field would not accept a NULL according to my table definition.

Comment: Unless you are inserting into the table from that function it shouldn't matter.